# Wordpress skipping functions with apply_filters?

Tags: wordpress, translation

I'm using a translation plugin which creates a hook for the_title, the_content and other things.
All is working fine except one bit of code that does not display the title.
It uses this code:

```
$page_title = apply_filters('the_title',get_the_title());
```

If i try to use [get_the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) or [the_title()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title), it breaks.

What does apply filters do, and how do i make it not skip the hook from the translation plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_title` and `the_content` also exist in the Wordpress core. They are utilized for many things. Why a line like that is useful is apparent if you know what hooks are.

Filter hooks and Action hooks are essentially laundry lists. You can put functions on a hook, one after another so they form a queue, and when this hook is called on (by `do_action` and `apply_filters` respectively) Wordpress will unqueue one function after another. As it does, it will execute them.

```
add_action( 'test', 'func1' );
add_action( 'test', 'func2' );
do_action( 'test' ); // Executes func1 and then func2
```

The difference between actions and filters is that while they can both accept values, only filters will return a modified value. Actions do something that is important in and of itself; filters take a value and return a modified version of it that can be used later on. For example, to capitalize every title that's printed with `the_title` we can use the following piece of code:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function( $title ) {
    return strtoupper( $title );
});
```

Since we know that all functions hooked on `the_title` - the hook and not the function - will be executed only by `apply_filters` we expect to find it somewhere in function `the_title`. Actually that function is basically `echo get_the_title` and here's how `get_the_title` looks:

```
function get_the_title( $id = 0 ) {
        $post = &get_post($id);

        $title = isset($post->post_title) ? $post->post_title : '';
        $id = isset($post->ID) ? $post->ID : (int) $id;

        if ( !is_admin() ) {
                if ( !empty($post->post_password) ) {
                        $protected_title_format = apply_filters('protected_title_format', __('Protected: %s'));
                        $title = sprintf($protected_title_format, $title);
                } else if ( isset($post->post_status) && 'private' == $post->post_status ) {
                        $private_title_format = apply_filters('private_title_format', __('Private: %s'));
                        $title = sprintf($private_title_format, $title);
                }
        }
        return apply_filters( 'the_title', $title, $id );
}
```

I'm posting the entire function because learning to look for hooks in the source code is of utmost importance for bourgeoning Wordpress developers. The source code is littered with hooks, and so they can be used to modify many aspects of the built-in functions of Wordpress. Now that you've located `apply_filters( 'the_title', ... )` in the source code, you can appreciate its importance!

`the_title` simply echoes the value given to it by `get_the_title` and you can modify or even replace the value that `get_the_title` returns by attaching a filter to the hook `the_title`!

Now, I hope you don't think all that I've written so far is gratuitous. In fact, now we can easily answer your main question which was "why does it not work?"

First of all, you can never pass `the_title` to a function! It would be like writing `somefunction( $var1, echo $var2, $var3 )`. We cannot pass a value to a function by using echo, because echo sends  its output to the browser.

The better attempt is the one you posted

```
$page_title = apply_filters('the_title',get_the_title());
```

But as we've seen, `get_the_title` has applied `the_title` to its return value already. You're simply applying all those functions a second time. It could result in strangeness if you have some custom filters attached to `the_title` or it could do nothing. So it either muddles the result or is gratuitous. Which is why you should simply do this:

```
$page_title = get_the_title();
```

Now, you also said

> All is working fine except one bit of code that does not display the
>   title

This is confusing, because we would not expect a variable assignment to output anything! To output the title, you could do this

```
$page_title = get_the_title();
echo $page_title;
```

But as we've learned, this is really (look at the source code for the slight difference) the same as:

```
the_title();
```

So I wrote quite a lot just to come to the conclusion that you probably want to use `the_title` on its own. But I hope this can be a good resource on filter/action hooks as well.

Any questions are welcome.

Comment: You have wisdom beyond your age! Thank you o Wordpress guru, i was mixing vars and functions which lead to my demise! You have solved my problem, and indebted me a beer!